# Python version upgrade

Tags: python, ubuntu, version

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.7, python 3.6+ version is required for my software
I checked the version by

```
$ `python3 --version
Python 3.5.2`
```

I run the below instructions to upgrade, but they don`t affect python version (above)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch versions with update-alternatives, which should come with a typical ubuntu install.

`sudo update-alternatives --config python`

`python --version`

Have a look [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-multiple-alternative-versions-of-python-on-ubuntu-20-04-237be5177474)
**